# Android dynamic imageview not loading completely

Tags: android, view

I am adding multiple views to my linearlayout dynamically using async task. In the first run images are not loading completely, its loading only 60- 80 % only. 
images are fetching through web service and adding dynamically to view. It will load completely only after i go back and come to the page or after taking another page.

please check following image.

[image]

all view are adding dynamically. also using progress dialog for async task.

Comment: Consider using a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` if you are adding a lot of data

Comment: thankz for your tip, let me try.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to use this [Image Loader Library](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to load those images dynamically with ease. Use a ListView with your own Adapter and add the loading image code there.